# How can I start using Snappy compression in Ubuntu after installation?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, software-installation, execute-command, compression

I have recently installed google's snappy compression library ([link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libsnappy1v5/download)) in my Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) machine. As I want to use the library to compress and decompress the files of my interest, what are the set of terminal commands I should use to achieve it?